# Discord JS | Cannot read property 'removeRole' of undefined

Tags: javascript, list, discord.js

I'm creating a bot that will assign roles depending on a certain value of a double dimension array (Membres variable). 
When I'm typing my command "!modification someone = -number", I should get back the role "Esclave" and a specific message since the value is negative (see code for explanation). But instead, I get an error saying that the 60th line which is exactly the same as others is not working. I find this very confusing since a few moments before, **everything worked fine.**

Here's the error

```
C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\index.js:57
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Esclave")).catch(console.error);;
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeRole' of undefined
    at level (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\index.js:57:25)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\index.js:112:29)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)        
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)       
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Pavilion\Desktop\Imprimerie\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
```

Here's my code:

```
bot.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    function level(Membres){
        for (let i = 0; i < Membres.length; i++) {
            const member1 = message.guild.members.get(Membres[i][2]);
            if (Membres[i][1]< 0){
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Brigand"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Empereur"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Corsaire"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Grand Corsaire"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Super Nova"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Pirate"));
                member1.addRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Esclave"))
                message.channel.sendMessage(Membres[i][0] + " est devenu un Esclave !");
            }
            if (Membres[i][1] >= 0 & Membres[i][1] < 100000){
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Esclave")).catch(console.error);;
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Empereur"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Corsaire"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Grand Corsaire"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Super Nova"));
                member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Pirate"));
                member1.addRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Brigand"))
                message.channel.sendMessage(Membres[i][0] + " est devenu un Brigand !");
            }
        }
        return message.guild.roles;
    }
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'modification':
            if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Propriétaire")) return message.channel.send("Tu n'as pas vraiment le droit de faire ça...")
            for (let oudex  = 0; oudex < Membres.length; oudex++) {
                if (args[1] == Membres[oudex][0]){
                    switch (args[2]){
                        case "+":
                            Membres[oudex][1] = Membres[oudex][1] + parseInt(args[3]);
                            message.channel.sendMessage("Augmentation ! la prime de " + Membres[oudex][0]+ " est désormais de " + Membres[oudex][1] + " Berrys !");
                            level(Membres);
                            return Membres[oudex][1]
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            Membres[oudex][1] = Membres[oudex][1] - parseInt(args[3]);
                            message.channel.sendMessage("Diminution ! la prime de " + Membres[oudex][0]+ " est désormais de " + Membres[oudex][1] + " Berrys !");
                            level(Membres);
                            return Membres[oudex][1]
                            break;
                        case "=":
                            Membres[oudex][1] = parseInt(args[3]);
                            message.channel.sendMessage("Assignation ! la prime de " + Membres[oudex][0]+ " est désormais de " + Membres[oudex][1] + " Berrys !");
                            level(Membres);
                            return Membres[oudex][1]
                            break;      
                    }
                }
            }    
    }
})
```

And here's the "Membres" variable (id is a string object containing the ID of everybody in the server) :

```
Membres = [["ener", 0, id], ["zoro", 0, id],
["mihawk", 0, id], ["crocodile", 0, id],
["chopper", 0, id],["sugar", 0, id],
["bonclay", 0, id], ["katakuri", 0, id],
["bellamy", 0, id], ["arlong", 0, id],
["barbe blanche", 0, id], ["alvida", 0, id],
["sanji", 0, id, ["ben beckman", 0, id]];
```

I've looked up many differents topics online. Some said that I need to check if my guild exists: But if my Discord exists, shouldn't that mean that my guild exists? Why do I need to check?

Comment: The for loop is never finished, the first matching case will end the execution of the function.

Comment: I'm new to javascript but I don't understand why it causes the problem. When I set the value to a negative one, the first matching case is the first and it will stop the execution of the function. That's fine. If the execution is stopped at the matching case, why does the program needs to check the other cases? (The line causing the problem is ```if (Membres[i][1] >= 0 & Membres[i][1] < 100000){
                **member1.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find('name', "Esclave")).catch(console.error)**;;```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `message.guild.members.get(Membres[i][2])` is returning a result. There are a few reasons it wouldnt, the biggest of wich is a member leaving the server but the object still existing in the `Membres` array. Just add a `if(!member1) { continue; }` right after you define member1.

Also i noticed that the data you posted for `Membres` is incorrect

`["sanji", 0, id, ["ben beckman", 0, id]];`

```
              ^^^^
      No closing bracket for 'sanji' object
```

I dont know if that was just an error when you posted the question but if its actually whats in your code your basically running
`message.guild.members.get(["ben beckman", 0, id]);` And obviously that returns undefined.

Comment: That's just an error when I wrote the question. Actually, I changed a little bit of the code and replaced all the 'if' by a switch. Right now, the code looks like this and I'm still getting the error despite adding "if(!member) {continue;}" : ``` for (let i = 0; i < Membres.length; i++) {
            const member1 = message.guild.members.get(Membres[i][2]);
            if (!member1){
                member1.removeRoles(member1.roles); ```

Comment: I'm still getting error ```Cannot read property 'removeRoles' of undefined```

Comment: The new if statement needs to be directly after the declaration of ``member1``. const member1= (whatever); if(!member1){continue;}